# Efficiently retrieve Z ordered objects in viewport in 2D game

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, graphics, game-engine

Imagine a 2D game with a large play area, say 10000x10000 pixels. Now imagine there are thousands of objects spread across this area. All the objects are in a Z order list, so every object has a well-defined position relative to every other object even if they are far away.

Suppose there is a viewport in to this play area showing say a 500x500 area of this play area. Obviously if the algorithm is "for each object in Z order list, if inside viewport, render it" then you waste a lot of time iterating all the thousands of objects far outside the viewport. A better way would be to maintain a Z-ordered list of objects near or inside the viewport.

If both the objects and the viewport are moving, what is an efficient way of maintaining a Z-ordered list of objects which are candidates to draw? This is for a general-purpose game engine so there are not many other assumptions or details you can add in to take advantage of: the problem is pretty much just that.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to keep your memory layout strongly ordered by Z. Instead you need to store your objects in a space partitionning structure that is oriented along the viewing surface.
A typical partitionning structure, is a **quad-tree**, in 2D. You can use a **binary tree**, you can use a **grid**, or you can use a **spatial hashing scheme**. You can even mix those techniques and combine them one into each other.
There is no "best", but you can put in the balance the ease of writing and maintaining the code. And the memory you have available.
Let us consider the grid, it is the most simple to implement, fastest to access, and easiest to traverse. (traversing is the fact of going to neighborhood cells)

Imagine you allow yourself 20MB of RAM usage for your grid skeleton, considering the cell content is just a small object (like a std::vector or a c# List), say 50 bytes. for a 10k pixels square surface you then have:

```
sqrt(20*1024*1024 / 50) = 647
```

you get 647 cells for one dimension, therefore 10k/647 = 15 pixels wide cells.
Still very small, so I suppose perfectly acceptable. You can adjust the numbers to get cells of 512 pixels for example. It should be a good fit when a few cells fit in the viewport.

Then, it is trivially easy to determine which cells are activated by the viewport, by dividing the top left corner by the size of the cell and flooring that result, this gives you the index directly in the cell. (provided both your viewport space and grid space start at 0,0 both. otherwise you need to offset)
Finally take the bottom right corner, determine the grid coordinate for the cell; and you can do a dual loop (x and y) between the min and max to iterate over the activated cells.
When treating a cell, you can draw the objects it contains by going through the list of objects that you would have previously stowed.

Beware of objects that spans over 2 cells or more. You need to make a choice, either store them once and only, but then your search algorithms will always need to know the size of the biggest element in the region and also search the lists of the neighbooring cells (by going as far as necessary to be sure to cover at least the size of this biggest element).
Or, you can store it multiple times (my prefered way), and simply make sure when you iterate cells, that you treat objects once only per frame. This is very easily achieved by using a frame id, in the object structure (as a mutable member).

This same logic applies for more flexible parition like binary trees.

I have implementation for both available in my engine, check the code out, it may help you get through the details: http://sourceforge.net/projects/carnage-engine/

Final words about your Z Ordering, if you had multiple memory storage for each Z, then you already did a space partitionning, simply not along the good axis.
This can be called layering.
What you can do as an optimization, is instead of storing lists of objects in your cells, you can store (ordered) `map`s of objects and their keys is their Z, therefore the iteration will be ordered along Z.

Comment: This is a good approach, but suppose you have two large objects both overlapping each other across a cell border (so they're both in two cells). How do you ensure they are displayed with the correct Z order without having to simply run a gather-and-sort every frame? Even if each cell contains its instances in Z order, they still have to be rendered correctly relative to the other on-screen cells, so how can that be done efficiently?

Comment: You can just do essentially a merge sort on the visible cells before rendering.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: ahah awesome comment. I actually thought about that situation when writing the anwser, I just didn't want to clog it with more details and let it slip under the carpet. It shows you understood every bits of what I said, that's nice because I thought I was going too fast. Do you think the gather and sort at each frame would be too slow ? It depends on the machine you need that to run, but as of today, recent smartphones (~2Ghz) are going to handle that no problem, as long as the sorting doesn't trigger allocations/garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution to this sort of problem is to group your objects according to their approximate XY location. For example, you can bucket them into 500x500 regions, i.e. objects intersecting [0,500]x[0,500], objects intersecting [500,1000]x[0,500], etc. Very large objects might be listed in multiple buckets, but presumably there are not too many very large objects.

For each viewport, you would need to check at most 4 buckets for objects to render. You will generally only look at about as many objects as you need to render anyway, so it should be efficient. This does require a bit more work updating when you reposition objects. However, assuming that a typical object is only in one bucket, it should still be pretty fast.

Comment: But this forces you to merge the Z order for every object in the visible buckets every frame, right? Otherwise large objects overlapping multiple buckets will display at the wrong Z order. I think having to do all that merging every frame is likely to be too much overhead.

Comment: Are you worried about merging Z-orders of 4 different buckets? That doesn't seem too bad. If you have N objects visible, you're going to take O(N) time to render them anyway, unless you expect a lot of them to be clipped by things in front.